# c++ nested loop output result

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I want to output this result at screen :

> 1
>  23
>  456
>  78910

how to do that??
I tried to write this code:

```
for (int line = 1; line <= 4; line++){
    int num = line;
    int i = 1;
    for (int x = 1; x <= line; x++){
        cout << num;
        num = num + i;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

but the output is :

> 1
> 23
> 345
> 4567

please help !!!

Comment: Try stepping through your code in a debugger, watching the how the variables change value -- there's a good chance you'll figure out why it's not working! :-)

Comment: `num` should initialize to 1 outside of the loop.  Currently, it loses its count every time the outer loop increments.  Also, `i` is pointlessly constant to 1, and `num = num + i;` is equivalent to `++num;`.

Comment: Get rid of `num=line;` in the outer loop.

Comment: `num` can't equal `line` every time.. see how it is 1,2,3,4. It needs to be 1, then add 1, then add 2, then add 3.

Comment: @Aggieboy --> thank's a lot .. job done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `num` outside the `for` loop and increment it after you write it out.

```
int num = 1;
for (int line = 1; line <= 4; line++){
    for (int x = 1; x <= line; x++){
        cout << num;
        ++num;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 1;
int i = 1;
for (int line = 1; line <= 4; line++){
    for (int x = 1; x <= line; x++){
        cout << num;
        num = num + i;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```